# 英語が残っている：改善待ちバナーに put on hold as ... by

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

標題のとおりです。英語の語順のまま部分的に翻訳されているようですね。
語順含めて表現をいじれるのなら、次のような文面を提案します。

この質問は投票により「`質問の範囲が広すぎる`」を理由として`8時間前`に改善待ちとなりました（投票者：`xxxx` `yyyy`）。

[image: 改善待ちバナー]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一行目がだいぶ長くなるので「投票により」を削ってみました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あとは句点の位置が気になりますが、こういうものでしょうか……。

Comment: ありがとうございます。句点を括弧の後にするか前にするかは、サイト全体でどちらかに統一されていれば良いのではないでしょうか。和訳する際のガイドラインがあるのなら今後はそれに従います。